# How to use afterRender and rebuild from fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I've read the documentation regarding afterRender from the fullpage.js github page. In my site I have content that is generated by AJAX in a particular div.

Example below

```
$("#fullpage").fullpage({
    afterRender: {
        // I don't know what to put here
    }
});

$("#btn-generate-content").on("click", function() {
    // Target the div
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_topic_content.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // Place the data in the div
        }

    });
});
```

With the code above, I'm generating a long paragraph and placing it into a div. Now I want my site to resize accordingly to the generated paragraph. How can I use *reBuild()* on the *afterRender* to **target this particular div when it has finished rendering the content**.

Answer (score 1):

After get ajax content you should use $.fn.fullpage.rebuild() in a callback.

I don't see an action of placing html content.
It should be done in success function, and then you should call rebuild function.